# What if I don't put a return value to a function whose prototype returns a value

Tags: c++, return, return-value

I have just spend 3 hours, probably more, trying to find a bug, segfault or bad_allow, depending on the way I modified the code so as to understand what object was messing with the stack or memory: I put all my objects in doubt... I slaughtered classes... ( nonetheless this turned out to be good since those classes revealed themselves useless in the end :-) )...

But, indeed, the real mistake was simply:
**I hadn't written a return statement** in a function that should return a value (in my case I needed to return a `std::vector<boost::any>`).

I thought that **gcc (4.6.3)** couldn't have compiled without it.
And I feel even stranger remembering that something similar has happened to me with **ms visual 2010**.

So now I am wondering whether it is legal not to write a return statement ??
What happens in such cases ?

Is it related with the fact that the main that can have a return value or not ?
Or should I consider going to **gcc 4.7** ?

Comment: It's undefined behavior.

Comment: BUt why does it compile ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland it shouldn't. I know VC 2010 doesn't (at least for me).

Comment: @MrUniverse No, a compiler is not required to reject such a program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's undefined behaviour:

> `[C++11: 6.6.3/2]:` *[..]* Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a `return` with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

It compiles because:

1. the compiler is not required to diagnose it;
2. diagnosing this is not always trivial, so *your* compiler doesn't bother;
3. C++ is a "do it yourself" language.

Comment: I don't understand the 3rd point ?

Comment: The third part is "C++ is a language where if you do something bad, you have to blame only yourself". Most compilers, with sufficient warnings will warn for this sort of thing. But some may not - and some compilers only when you turn on optimisation, because it requires some of the "flow analysis" that is part of optimisation.

Comment: @StephaneRolland C++ has no intention of holding your hand. You must remember your `return` statements yourself.

Answer (score 5):

If you compile with the flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` It should give you a compiler warning about a function that should return a value but doesn't do so.

Comment: oh, I only have -Wall. I haven't put `-Wextra` and `-pedantic`. I'm gonna add it right now.

Comment: @StephaneRolland - but watch out: you may get false warnings.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'll keep your remark in mind. But for the moment it only complains about extra `;` I find that funny. I'm removing them so as not to drown future serious warnings. (Ah I forgot a signed unsigned comparison).

Comment: @Pete: What "false warnings"?