# If a function with int as specified return type, does not have any return statement, i.e. does not return a value, will it return garbage value?

Tags: c++

This program, prints garbage value for the cout inside main function.

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int f(int num)
{
    cout<<num<<endl;   
}
int main()
{
   cout << f(5) << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

5

6296224

Is there some rule like this?

Comment: Undefined behaviour means anything.

Comment: A good reason to compile with the `-Wall` switch. Specifically, `-Wreturn-type` would have gotten you a warning.

Comment: See also: [How do C++ progs get their return value, when a return is not specified in the function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459810/how-do-c-progs-get-their-return-value-when-a-return-is-not-specified-in-the-f),  and [What if I don't put a return value to a function whose prototype returns a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057718/what-if-i-dont-put-a-return-value-to-a-function-whose-prototype-returns-a-value)

Comment: I removed the C tag because the code is C++. They are two different languages, especially since you are asking a question about the corner of language detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, it will invoke undefined behavior if the return value is used:

> (C11, 6.9.1p12) "If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the       value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined."

In C++, the function call is undefined behavior:

> (C++11, 6.6.3p2) "Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function."

Comment: Note that in C++, the value doesn't even have to be used for it to be undefined behaviour.

Comment: Too bad it is a C reference, rather than a C++ reference.

Comment: @CodyGray the question was initially tagged C and C++, I added the quote for C++.

Comment: Hmm, okay. It always had `cout` though, and I've never seen that in C code. :-)

Comment: except for main() function, where return is not required