# Why isn't my "else if" statement working?

Tags: c++, if-statement, factorial

For some reason my `else if` statement is not working. When I run the code with the input "20", I get the expression for the factorial back then for "20", when  my `else if` statement should correct for this.

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned int factorial(unsigned int number);

int main()
{
    unsigned int number;
    std::cout << "Please enter a positive interger. ";
    std::cin >> number;
    std::cout << "facorial of " << number << " = " << factorial(number);
    return 0;
}

unsigned int factorial(unsigned int number)
{
    if (number > 1 && number < 20) {
        return number * factorial(number - 1);
    }
    else if (number >= 20) {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking? The else if that catches 20, should be returning "error".

Answer (score 2):

You don't return out of your else if, resulting in an undefined return from your factorial function:
[What if I don't put a return value to a function whose prototype returns a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057718/what-if-i-dont-put-a-return-value-to-a-function-whose-prototype-returns-a-value)

The number you're getting is not the result of the function, but instead is an undefined value.

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned int factorial(unsigned int number);

int main()
{
    unsigned int number;
    std::cout<< "Please enter a positive interger. ";
    std::cin >> number;
    std::cout << "facorial of " << number << " = " << factorial(number);
    return 0;
}

unsigned int factorial(unsigned int number)
{
    if (number > 1 && number < 20){
        return number * factorial(number - 1);
        }
    else if (number >= 20){
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
        return 0;
        }
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Hey I know its been a long time since I posted this, but i just wanted to thank you for your reply. I appreciate it.