# Recursively counting a number of values that satisfies a condition and return that number

Tags: c++, recursion

I need to count how many cubes of values between a and b (2 and 9 in this example) end with numbers between 2 and 5. Everything has to be done with recursion.

The output of this code is

part c = recc = 4
32767
0

It does not make sense to me. It calculates the value of n correctly, but then once asked to return it, returns either 0 or 32767, as if it was not defined.

Can anyone pinpoint the issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void partb(int a, int b){
    if(a<=b){
        int p = (a*a*a)%10;
    else if(p>=2 && p<=5){
        cout<<a*a*a<<" ";
      }
    partb(a+1, b);
    }
}
int recc(int n, int a, int b){
    int p = (a*a*a)%10;
    if(a>b){
        cout<<"recc = " << n << endl;
        return n;
    }
    else if(a<=b){
        if(p>=2 && p<=5){
            n++;
        }
        recc(n, a+1, b);
    }
}
int partc(int a, int b){
    int n = recc(0, a, b);
    cout<<endl<< "part c = " << recc(0, a, b) << endl;
    return n;
}
int main(){
    int n=partc(2,9);
    cout << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if I don't put a return value to a function whose prototype returns a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057718/what-if-i-dont-put-a-return-value-to-a-function-whose-prototype-returns-a-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all control paths in your function return a value, so you were getting undefined behaviour when using the return value.

Now, this wasn't helped by the fact that the function itself is needlessly complicated.  Let's rewrite it to use common practice for recursion:

```
int recc(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b) return 0;
    int p = (a*a*a)%10;
    int n = (p>=2 && p<=5) ? 1 : 0;
    return n + recc(a+1, b);
}
```

Now your function is simpler.  The recursion termination condition is right at the top.  The function then decides whether `a` will contribute 1 or 0 to the count.  And finally you return that value plus the count for a smaller range.

Notice how `return n + recc(a+1, b);` has broken the problem into a simple local solution combined with the recursive result of a reduced scope.

The invocation becomes simpler too, because you no longer have to pass in a redundant argument:

```
int partc(int a, int b)
{
    int n = recc(a, b);
    cout << endl << "part c = " << n << endl;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Should also be another problem in OP's code in `partb` with `else if(p>=2 && p<=5)` not being properly associated with an `if`. Looks like this could just be a missing brace added in the wrong spot to silence a compiler error.

Comment: Good spotting.  I didn't even read that function because it wasn't used anywhere.